# How do I create a block only for the user "owning" the profile page?

Tags: views, users, blocks

I made so the logged in user have a recap of their last comments/added node on their profile with a view.
As I am making the profile page public, I need to be able to hide those blocks from others authenticated users.

How can I make the block visible to the user for which the profile page is?

Answer (score 0):

So I found out :

- Either you can directly go in view and add a "FILTER CRITERIA" > "(author) User: Current" and it will hide the content for user that are not the current logged in user
- Or you can go in the block settings, select "Pages on which this PHP code returns TRUE (experts only)" and add in the box `<?php global $user;
  return $user->uid == arg(1); ?>` and the block disappear totally if you are not the current user.